# How to authenticate users with facebook login in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, oauth, facebook-oauth

Hi i am working on a web project using java i want to user of website to log in using their Facebook account.I tried [Facebook Developer official](http://www.developer.facebook.com)

but didn't get the solution

Answer (score 8):

I can recommend you OAuth library [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java), or its improved fork [Subscribe](https://github.com/hhru/subscribe). If you are interested in usage samples, take a look at my project [OAuh JEE Login](http://www.literak.cz/OAuthLogin/).

First you need to get OauthService instance:

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(FacebookApi.class)
            .apiKey("key").apiSecret("secret")
            .scope("email").callback("https://hostname/endpoint/")
            .build();
```

Then you need to redirect user to facebook page where he will grant access to your application / log in:

```
String redirectUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(NULL_TOKEN);
response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
```

Facebook will then call your callback uri and you need to grab parameter `code` and get access token:

```
String verifierValue = request.getParameter("code");
if (verifierValue == null) {
    log.warn("Callback did not receive code parameter!");
    return false;
}

Verifier verifier = new Verifier(verifierValue);
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(NULL_TOKEN, verifier);
```

Finally it is time to use this token to ask Facebook for user details:

```
OAuthRequest resourceRequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, RESOURCE_URL);
service.signRequest(accessToken, resourceRequest);
Response resourceResponse = resourceRequest.send();

JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(resourceResponse.getBody());
JsonValue value = jsonObject.get("username");
```

See the class [FacebookOAuthProcessor](https://github.com/literakl/OAuthLogin/blob/master/OAuthLogin-ejb/src/main/java/cz/literak/oauth/services/FacebookOAuthProcessor.java).

Comment: @TechGuy - do you have any question?

Comment: Hi, can you please check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891464/spring-mvc-facebook-authorization-works-but-unable-to-access-api?noredirect=1#comment49822656_30891464

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Scribe.

Check out an example of how to using Facebook with scribe here : 
https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java

Comment: How about a full example? I have struggles to understand why my current web application validates the user using Facebook, but it simply returns the same Facebook ID for each user. I really want to find a working start-end example, for the sake of understanding how everything works.