# Facebook, gmail, twitter login with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, oauth, facebook-oauth

I followed this quesion [How to authenticate users with facebook login in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569036/how-to-authenticate-users-with-facebook-login-in-java) but its hard to follow it. The Web application is dependent on Ejb application and therefore I am unable to run it on netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twitter4j and Facebook4j api to solve you problem it is very easy to use [Twitter4j Login Sample](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#signinwithtwitter)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException, IOException{
    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + " : " + status.getText());
        }
        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}
        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}
        public void onException(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
    TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    // sample() method internally creates a thread which manipulates TwitterStream and calls these adequate listener methods continuously.
    twitterStream.sample();
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/yusuke/sign-in-with-twitter) you can check simple JSP example how to create Login with Twitter

Answer (score -1):

for that first you need to create a developer account in any application you want perform the direct login.
then from that account or platform you have to create the dummy project and get the api key and before that you need to create the login page with authentication and authorization with session handling and then you can add the particular api key into your configuration file of the project and you will get functionallity.